# Plot for a polynomial with multi-variable as parameters

Tags: plotting

I would like to generate a Plot for a multi-variable polynomial. When I try the code below:

```
Plot[
  -(1/((-4 + b^2) e))(2 e Subscript[a, 1] + b e Subscript[a, 2] + 
    2 e Subscript[c, 1] + b e Subscript[c, 2] + 2 e Subscript[h, 1] + 
    2 k^2 Subscript[h, 1] - 2 b k m Subscript[h, 1] + 
    2 m^2 Subscript[h, 1] + b e Subscript[h, 2] + 
    b k^2 Subscript[h, 2] - 4 k m Subscript[h, 2] + 
    b m^2 Subscript[h, 2]),
  {b, 10}, {k, 10}, {m, 1}, {e, 10},
  {Subscript[c, 1], 50}, {Subscript[c, 2], 70},
  {Subscript[a, 1], 30}, {Subscript[a, 2], 60},
  {Subscript[h, 1], 1, 5}, {Subscript[h, 2], 5}
 ]
```

I get the error message:

> ```
> Plot::nonopt: Options expected (instead of {Subscript[h, 2],5}) beyond position 2 in Plot[-((2 e Subscript[a, 1]+b e Subscript[a, 2]+2 e Subscript[c, 1]+b e Subscript[c, 2]+2 e Subscript[h, 1]+2 k^2 Subscript[h, 1]-2 b k m Subscript[h, 1]+2 m^2 Subscript[h, 1]+b e Subscript[h, 2]+b k^2 Subscript[h, 2]-4 k m Subscript[h, 2]+b m^2 Subscript[h, 2])/((-4+b^2) e)),{b,10},{k,10},{m,1},{e,10},{Subscript[c, 1],50},{Subscript[c, 2],70},{Subscript[a, 1],30},{Subscript[a, 2],60},{Subscript[h, 1],1,5},{Subscript[h, 2],5}]. An option must be a rule or a list of rules.
> ```

How to deal with the error message??
Thanks for all help!!

Comment: I am extremely confused by your syntax. What sort of plot do you expect here? It looks like you have 10 different independent variables that you are trying to plot against. This doesn't make sense! `Plot` wants *one* independent variable. Are you perhaps forgetting a `Table` or something?

Comment: It is because of two things. First, you can make a 2D or 3D plot, but you try to do a plot in a multidimensional space with the dimension moree than 3. That does not work. Second, if you reduce the dimension to 2 or 3, you need to correctly give the limits of the plot, which is not the case in your code. I suggest that you first look into Menu/Help/WolframDocumentation/Plot.

Comment: I propose to close this question as an off-topic, since it is based on elementary lack of the syntax knowledge.

Comment: Sorry about my bad syntax. I have found where the problem is. I should try Manipulate